# How to navigate from child component to some othe page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have Login.js and List.js in 'pages' folder while Form.js in 'component' folder. Form.js is a child component of Login.js . When I want to navigate from Login.js to List.js I simply use `onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('List')` but if I use this same code in Form.js it says:  Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function from Login to Form to execute that function from Login

Function Component form

```js
const Login = props => {
    const goToList = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('List')
    }

    return (
        <Form redirectList={goToList} />
    )
}

const Form = props => {
    props.redirectList()  // This will execute the navigate from Login component
}
```

Class Component form

```js
class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.goToList = function(){
            this.props.navigation.navigate('List')
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <Form redirectList={this.goToList} />
        )
    }
}

class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.redirectToList = function(){
            props.redirectList();
        }
    }
    // You can redirect to list using
    this.redirectToList();
}
```

Comment: `<Form redirectList={goToList} />`  in this line showing :Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')

Comment: @AbhijeetGupta if you're using the class form it should be `this.goToList`

Comment: Thnx it worked but is it the only way of doing this..cant i directly use the createStackNavigator

Comment: @AbhijeetGupta probably there is, but i can't help you out more without knowing what libraries you're using and how you are implementing them, btw you can also pass `this.props.navigation` as a prop to Form so you can execute `this.props.navigation.navigate('List')` from Form too

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your code so I can't tell that this is exactly what you are looking for, but try something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

export function Form() {
  const ListBtn = withRouter(({ history }) => (
    <button onClick={() => {history.push('/list')}}>
      Go to list
    </button>
  ))

  return (
    <ListBtn />
  )
}
```